# Mercurial subrepo - changed .hgsub file but it still tries to pull from old server

Tags: mercurial, subrepos

I have a mercurial repo with a subrepo:

```
repo
  subrepo
  .hgsub
```

The .hgsub originally had

```
subrepo = https://<domain>/user/repo
```

and domain was set up with my dns to point to bitbucket (I was playing around with their custom domains feature).

I've now changed .hgsub to:

```
subrepo = https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo
```

But when I try to pull from the subrepo I get the error:

```
abort: <domain> certificate error: certificate is for bitbucket.org
```

Which means it is still trying to pull from my domain rather than from bitbucket.

I've checked my `repo/subrepo/.hg/hgrc` file and it correctly updated to:

```
[paths]
default = https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo
```

Why is it still trying to pull from the old domain?

If I try to push from `repo` then it pushes correctly to bitbucket.

Edit: Actually, push from the subrepo doesn't work but does work from the parent repo

`repo > push` - works, pushes to bitbucket

`subrepo > pull` - doesn't work, tries to pull from my domain

`subrepo > push` - doesn't work, tries to pull from my domain

Comment: So in your last actual revision your `.hgsub` has correct path?

Comment: Yes, the `.hgsub` has the correct path, I have both committed and pushed it to the remote repo. `push` works fine but `pull` and `incoming` throw the same error.

Comment: Edited question, `push` works from the parent repo but not from the subrepo.

Comment: have you re-cloned the nested repository after changed `.hgsub`?

Comment: Just did, and that fixed it. I guess it is cached somewhere. If you add an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-clone the nested repository after you have changed `.hgsub`